# finding the laplacian beltrami operator?

Tags: differential-geometry, laplacian

the matrix $ \begin{bmatrix} g_{11} & g_{12} \\ g_{21} & g_{22}  \end{bmatrix} $
=      $ \begin{bmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&r{(\gamma )^2}\end{bmatrix}$

[image: kj]

what i did is $$\nabla^2f=\frac{1}{r(\gamma)} [\partial _\gamma((r(\gamma ) \partial_{\gamma})+\partial_{\theta}(r(\gamma)^3\partial_{\theta})])$$

$$=\frac{1}{r(\gamma)}[\dot{r}{(\gamma)\frac {\partial}{\partial \gamma} +r(\gamma) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \gamma^2}+r(\gamma)^3 \frac {\partial ^2}{\partial \theta^2}}]
$$
but in the book it is $$ =\frac{1}{r(\gamma)}[\dot{r}{(\gamma)\frac {\partial}{\partial \gamma} +r(\gamma) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \gamma^2}+1/r(\gamma)\frac {\partial ^2}{\partial \theta^2}}]$$.
please tell where i am wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$g^{ij}$ represents the $ij$th element of $g^{-1}$ by convention, so you should have

$$\sqrt{|g|}g^{22} = r(\gamma)\cdot \frac{1}{r(\gamma)^2} = \frac{1}{r(\gamma)}$$

instead of

$$\sqrt{|g|}g^{22} = r(\gamma)\cdot r(\gamma)^2 = r(\gamma)^3$$

which is not correct. This is a fairly common mistake and one I've made a few times myself in this context. Note that the $11$ entry was unaltered (and thus you got the right expression for that part) since $g_{11} = 1$ so that $g^{11} = 1$.

In the [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator) for the Laplace-Beltrami operator, they also mention that $g^{ij}$ represents the $ij$th entry of $g^{-1}$ in the introduction.

Comment: if $g_{ij}$ ,$g^{i,j }$$i,j$ are in superscript then it's an inverse by convention

Comment: Right. Superscript refers to the inverse of the metric tensor, subscript refers to the original metric tensor.